# array filter of PDO result

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I get `PDO` rows array which contains the result:

```
parent_id , item_id

NULL        2
NULL        3
1           5
1           8
```

I want a new array where `parent_id` is not NULl

Means

```
new arr=[5,8]
```

Comment: In your query itself add condition like : `WHERE parent_id IS NOT NULL;`

Comment: thanks , I need all rows with parent is null , and reneed items with parent is not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set new array from exits or to duplicate request with **IS NULL** condition. With array method, your code will show like this:

```php
$arr = [
    [
        'parent_id' => null,
        'item_id' => 2,
    ],
    [
        'parent_id' => null,
        'item_id' => 4
    ],
    [
        'parent_id' => 2,
        'item_id' => 20,
    ],
];

$new_arr = array_filter($arr,function ($item) {
    return !$item['parent_id'];
});

print_r($new_arr);
```

Comment: Better to use return $item['parent_id'] === NULL; to get only entries for NULL or return $item['parent_id'] !== NULL; to get entries that are not NULL.
The expression !$item['parent_id'] also returns values for parent_id entries for 0 or "".